# Не работает обработчик нажатия кнопки PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, button

Не работает обработчик нажатия кнопки, хотя вроде делаю всё по примерам.

`.setText()` пробовал заменять на `print()`, в консоль ничего не выводило.

**main.py:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from code.main_window_ui import Ui_Form


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)

    def btn_clicked(self):
        self.ui.label_3.setText("Работает...")


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(form)
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


main()
```

**main_window_ui.py:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(367, 362)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem2, 4, 2, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setUnderline(True)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_3, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setLineWidth(1)
        self.label.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 2, 0, 1, 3)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 3, 0, 1, 3)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Парсер для avito.ru"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Начать"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Состояние парсера:"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Не активен"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Вставьте ссылку на страницу:"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, Вы объявили класс `MainWindow`, но не используете его. Вместо этого вы создаёте обычный `QtWidgets.QWidget` и создаёте `ui` для него. Поэтому:

```py
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    form = MainWindow()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Во-вторых, я не вникал в код, но Ваш UI написан под обычный `QWidget`, а не под `QMainWindow` (для `QMainWindow` он работает некорректно), поэтому `class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):`,

Comment: В-третьих класс `Ui_Form` как наследник - не нужен. `class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):`

Comment: Упустил это, согласен.